# Tab background with DynamicResource not working in Visual Studio 2013 extension

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, tabcontrol, dynamicresource

I am developing a Visual Studio 2013 extension. Every control I use in a ToolWindowPane uses the same background than the current loaded Theme in Visual Studio, using this:

```
Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.ToolboxBackgroundKey}}"
```

I added tabs to one of the user control and I specified the background both in the `TabControl`, in the `StackPanel` inside the `ItemTemplate` and in a Style in `TabControl.Resources`, as follows:

```
<TabControl
    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.ToolboxBackgroundKey}}"
    >

<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.ToolboxBackgroundKey}}" />
        </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>

<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.ToolboxBackgroundKey}}">
```

But the headers still look like this:

[image: Tabs with a background color not fitting the whole header space]

**Is there a way to apply the Tab header style from Visual Studio to my TabControl, so it looks the same that the Visual Studio tabs?**

**Is there at least a way to remove this "white" background arround the styled part in the header?**

Thanks

Edit:

Paulo pointed me in the correct direction: I had to redefine the template for the TabItem. I followed the answer from this post: [How to make WPF TabItem Headers' Background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269217/how-to-make-wpf-tabitem-headers-background-transparent). I removed the corner radius and the margin when selected, and also used the VsBrushes for the colors:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
                            Name="TabItemBorder"
                            Margin="0,0,-4,0"
                            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.FileTabInactiveDocumentBorderBackgroundKey}}"
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                            >
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="TabItemContentSite"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="5,2,5,2"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.FileTabSelectedBackgroundKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: Tabs that look almost like the visual studio 2013 ones]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you gonna need to style the TabItem. If you use only the ItemTemplate, the system will replace just a small part of the default style.

With a new style you gonna have more control of what you are showing.

It looks like, the take control cannot have a valid VS theme.

Paulo Aboim Pinto

Comment: here you can get the default style
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035(v=vs.95).aspx

and change it removing the items that are giving you extra padding.